# Does a British Subject need a transit visa for Dubai?

Tags: transit-visas, dubai, uae

I'm traveling from Birmingham to Singapore with 2 hour stop over in Dubai. I have a British Subject passport. Do I need a visa for Dubai? I will stay airside.

Comment: Could you add some more information (and punctuation)? Are you planning on leaving the airport?

Comment: Is there any difference between a british subject passport and a british citizen/national passport?

Comment: I am not leaving the airport

Comment: A british citizen was born in Britain a british subject was born outside of Britain and now lives in Britain I was born in southern ireland

Comment: @Newton Yes they are quite different. British Subjects are basically people who were born somewhere in the old British Empire, but for some reason were not eligible to receive either (normal) British Citizenship or the citizenship of the new country. Many British Subjects are not entitled to live permanently in the UK.

Comment: "A british citizen was born in Britain": Under many circumstances, it's possible for a person born outside of Britain to be a British citizen.  I note this for the sake of accuracy, although the fact that you have a British Subject passport presumably means that the British authorities have already determined that your birth did not meet those circumstances.

Comment: Britain has about 6+ types of citizen-cum-subjects, with varying types of permissions to have-passport/passport-type/enter/live/work/leave and such.

Comment: In any case, if you stay airside, ticket is one itinerary, and you have onward ticket, you might not need transit visa for Dubai. With this above limited information, check with your airline, as they have the first say in letting you board flight for dubai.

Answer (score -1):

Considering that you only have a stop over and you will simply transit to the next flight (spend time in the transit lounge, airport duty free etc) a visa is not required because you will not be leaving the airport hence not entering the UAE hence no immigration/visa requirements.

Comment: Only British passports held by British Citizens can get 30 days on arrival. British Subjects need to apply for a visa.